# OpenGL - Using glReadPixels to read depth component returns incorrect values

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer, depth

I'm trying to read out the pixels of a texture that only has a depth component, however glReadPixels gives me an array where every value = 1.

Texture / Framebuffer creation:

```
GLuint frameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1,&frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1,&texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,width,height,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,m_depthTexture,0);
```

Reading from the texture:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);
float *depths = new float[width *height];
glReadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&depths[0]);
// glGetError reports no errors, but every value inside 'depths' is 1.
delete[] depths;
```

I didn't include the actual rendering to the texture, since I know that that works as it should.
This is what the depth texture looks like when I draw it on my main screen framebuffer:

[image]

It's definitely not empty, so why is it telling me the depth is 1 for all pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a desktop OpenGL version I suggest you use [glGetTexImage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) instead of glReadPixels.

Comment: I've tried it with glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&depths[0]); (after binding the texture to GL_TEXTURE_2D), however, that results in an exception ('Access violation writing location 0x0DBAB000.')

Comment: @Silverlan: Did you make sure that you had your depth texture bound when calling this?

Comment: Yeah, as I've said, I've bound it before the call: glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);

Comment: I found out what was causing the problems with glReadPixels, I was using the wrong width/height by accident.. Still, is there an advantage to using glGetTexImage?

Comment: @Silverlan: No not really and it's less portable. I suggested this as an alternative method for debugging the problem.